# Dividing 2 count statements in Postgresql

Tags: postgresql

I do have a question about the division of 2 count statements below, which give me the error underneath.

```
(SELECT COUNT(transactions.transactionNumber)
         FROM transactions
          INNER JOIN account ON account.sfid = transactions.accountsfid
          INNER JOIN transactionLineItems ON transactions.transactionNumber 
           = transactionLineItems.transactionNumber
          INNER JOIN products ON transactionLineItems.USIM = products.USIM
            WHERE products.gender = 'male' AND products.agegroup = 'adult' 
              AND transactions.transactionDate >= current_date - interval 
                  '730' day)/
            (SELECT COUNT(transactions.transactionNumber)
            FROM transactions
            WHERE transactions.transactionDate >= 
            current_date - interval '730' day)
```

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "/"
LINE 6: ...tions.transactionDate >= current_date - interval '730' day)/``
```

What I think the problem is, that the my count statements are creating tables, and the division of the tables is the problem, but how can I make this division work? 
Afterwards I want to check the result against a percentage, e.g. < 0.2.

Can anyone help me with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is that your complete query? Something like this works in Postgres 10:

`SELECT 
(SELECT COUNT(id) FROM test WHERE state = false) / (SELECT COUNT(id) FROM test WHERE state = true) as y`

The extra `SELECT` in front of both sub queries with the division is what's important. Otherwise I also get the error you mentioned.

See also my [DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/vEUnrCnUZRb22ps9wLCopS/0) version of this query.

Comment: Thanks a lot. This is working great! I just had to multiply it by 1.0,  so that it does not result to zero.